# How-to set up a network bridge on a laptop for LXC use?

Tags: linux, bridge, wireless-bridge

I am on a laptop using libvirt to run some containers.

By default it uses the `default` network provided by libvirt and the containers have a 192.168.122.0/24 network.

What I am trying to accomplish is that the container can be in the same network as my laptop (ie. 192.168.0.1/24).

This is what I've done:

```
#> ip link add type veth        // create a pair of veth
#> iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on    // allow WDS mode on my wifi
#> ifconfig veth0 up            // up veth0 interface
#> brctl addbr br0              // create br0
#> brctl addif br0 wlan0        // insert wlan0 in the bridge
#> brctl addif br0 veth0        // insert veth0 in the bridge
#> ifconfig br0 192.168.0.4/24  // assign the bridge the approriate ip
#> ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0       // free wlan0 ip
```

When I do apply that, I end up without Internet on my laptop; it seems like it can't get an IP address.

OS: Fedora 18
WiFi Card: Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N 6235
Wifi driver: `iwlwifi`
`modinfo iwlwifi output` is [here](http://pastebin.com/iqfy4yu7).

What is it I am missing so that wlan0 ends up without an IP address and thus without connectivity?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, I hope you are still interested in the answer I have written separately.

Answer (score 0):

I had not seen this message, originally. There is a solution to this.

First of all, let me say that I do not wish to use obsolte commands: the *iproute2* suite contains commands for all of this, including setting up virtual interfaces (something for which we once had to use openvpn or tunctl or uml-utilities) and creating bridges. If you do not know how to set up a bridge with *ip*, here we go:

```
  ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user root 

  ip link set tap0 up

  ip link add br0 type bridge

  ip link set tap0 master br0

  ip link set eth0 master br0

  ip addr add 10.173.10.1/24  dev br0

  ip link set br0 up
```

With this set of commands, we create a virtual interface called *tap0*, then a bridge called *br0*, then enslave *eth0* and *tap0* to the bridge, to which we assign an IP address of 10.173.10.1, then bring it all up. The three separate instances of bringing the interfaces up (for tap0, eth0, and br0) are required.

As for your problem. The trick to make this work is to use proxy-arp, which allows your pc (**not** your VM/Linux container/network namespace) to answer ARP queries in *their* stead.

In other words, by using IPv4 forwarding between your hardware interface and your virtual interface, you think you can connect your VM/LXC/NNS to your LAN as if it were a physical interface, but this is not true: you are forgetting the absolutely fundamental ARP traffic, which is what truly allows LAN to operate. So, the problem is: if I correctly forward IPv4 traffic, how can I also forward ARP traffic, so that my VM/LXC/NNS work? The trick is to use proxy-arp.

The full answer to that is in [Bohdi Zazen's blog](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/bridge-wireless-cards/), with the revealing title: *Bridge wireless cards*. He uses an obsolete package, *uml-utilities*, to create a virtual interface by means of the command *tunctl*: this is the only command for which he uses *uml-utilities*, so that you can safely neglect downloading the package, and use the command I wrote above to create a *tap* or *tun* interface, whichever you like, just modify the command accordingly. then create a veth pair for your LXC, and now create a bridge between tap0 and veth0. This bridge, called br0, is what you must *proxy-arp* for, instead of the simple tap0 interface described by Bohdi Zazen.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [guide for using a `nat bridge` with `lxc`](https://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/debian/61-debian-bridging-wireless-lxc-nat-bridge) which is a superior solution & works with `openvpn` & `dhcp`.

I've also written a [guide for a host bridge with wireless & `lxc`](http://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/debian/60-debian-bridging-wireless-lxc-host-bridge). It is a little of the [Bodhizazen note](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/bridge-wireless-cards/)s + [Debian Wiki notes](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections). This host bridge works as long as you are not also using `openvpn`.