# After connecting wlan0 to bridge interface (and then removing it), can't connect to AP

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian, bridge

I'm on a laptop running Debian Jessie with kernel 3.13-1-amd64; lspci shows that my wireless NIC + driver is

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

This has been working without any problems, until I tried creating a bridge for lxc containers to use. I did the same thing as this person here: [How-to set up a network bridge on a laptop for LXC use?](https://superuser.com/questions/616437/how-to-set-up-a-network-bridge-on-a-laptop-for-lxc-use) -- and ended up having the same problem as this poster did, so I decided to "undo" my actions.

This hasn't been successful.

Actions taken so far:

To configure the bridge:

```
#> ip link add type veth
#> iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on
#> ifconfig veth0 up
#> brctl addbr br0
#> brctl addif br0 wlan0
#> brctl addif br0 veth0
#> ifconfig br0 192.168.0.4/24  
#> ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0
```

To "deconfigure":

```
#> brctl delif br0 wlan0
#> brctl delif br0 veth0
#> iw dev wlan0 set 4addr off
#> ifconfig veth0 down
#> ifconfig wlan0 down
#> ifconfig br0 down
#> brctl delbr br0
```

Now, dmesg and /var/log/syslog show repeated attempts at connecting to the AP that was working before, which fail after authentication:

```
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname kernel: [11350.757172] wlan0: authenticate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname kernel: [11350.759036] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (try 1/3)
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (SSID='myaccesspoint' freq=2437 MHz)
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname kernel: [11350.762615] wlan0: authenticated
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname kernel: [11350.762753] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname kernel: [11350.762755] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname kernel: [11350.765080] wlan0: associate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (try 1/3)
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname kernel: [11350.767474] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (capab=0x411 status=12 aid=0)
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname kernel: [11350.767476] wlan0: 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 denied association (code=12)
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 status_code=12
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname kernel: [11350.788475] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 by local choice (reason=3)
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
May 27 09:16:01 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 27 09:16:02 myhostname dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (SSID='myaccesspoint' freq=2437 MHz)
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname kernel: [11354.559579] wlan0: authenticate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname kernel: [11354.561458] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (try 1/3)
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (SSID='myaccesspoint' freq=2437 MHz)
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname kernel: [11354.563445] wlan0: authenticated
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname kernel: [11354.563631] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname kernel: [11354.563633] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname kernel: [11354.565727] wlan0: associate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (try 1/3)
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: Associated with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname kernel: [11354.568091] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=9)
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname kernel: [11354.569030] wlan0: associated
May 27 09:16:04 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname kernel: [11354.978204] wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (Reason: 15)
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 reason=15
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname kernel: [11354.992729] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname kernel: [11354.995004] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname kernel: [11354.995005] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname kernel: [11354.995006] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname kernel: [11354.995007] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname kernel: [11354.995007] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname kernel: [11354.995008] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname kernel: [11354.995009] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname kernel: [11354.995010] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm)
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
May 27 09:16:05 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (SSID='myaccesspoint' freq=2437 MHz)
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname kernel: [11358.763968] wlan0: authenticate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname kernel: [11358.765796] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (try 1/3)
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (SSID='myaccesspoint' freq=2437 MHz)
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname kernel: [11358.769957] wlan0: authenticated
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname kernel: [11358.770102] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname kernel: [11358.770104] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname kernel: [11358.770846] wlan0: associate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (try 1/3)
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname kernel: [11358.773358] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (capab=0x411 status=12 aid=0)
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname kernel: [11358.773361] wlan0: 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 denied association (code=12)
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 status_code=12
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname kernel: [11358.802187] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 by local choice (reason=3)
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
May 27 09:16:09 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (SSID='myaccesspoint' freq=2437 MHz)
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname kernel: [11362.573442] wlan0: authenticate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname kernel: [11362.575270] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (try 1/3)
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (SSID='myaccesspoint' freq=2437 MHz)
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname kernel: [11362.580334] wlan0: authenticated
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname kernel: [11362.580503] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname kernel: [11362.580516] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname kernel: [11362.583508] wlan0: associate with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (try 1/3)
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: Associated with 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname kernel: [11362.585908] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=9)
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname kernel: [11362.586781] wlan0: associated
May 27 09:16:12 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname kernel: [11362.947693] wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 (Reason: 15)
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname wpa_supplicant[8946]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:18:f8:54:a3:d6 reason=15
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname kernel: [11362.973461] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname kernel: [11362.975673] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname kernel: [11362.975675] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname kernel: [11362.975676] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname kernel: [11362.975677] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname kernel: [11362.975678] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname kernel: [11362.975678] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname kernel: [11362.975679] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname kernel: [11362.975679] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm)
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
May 27 09:16:13 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 27 09:16:14 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long.
May 27 09:16:14 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [50 120 7]
May 27 09:16:14 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> Marking connection 'Auto myaccesspoint' invalid.
May 27 09:16:14 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'Auto myaccesspoint'
May 27 09:16:14 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
May 27 09:16:14 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
May 27 09:16:14 myhostname NetworkManager[13992]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
```

The things that jump out at me are "deauthenticating ... by local choice( reason=3)" and the lines that contain "(reason=15)".

I've tried various fixes:

- iwconfig wlan0 power off
- killing wpa_supplicant
- connecting with iwconfig + dhclient instead of gnome's network -manager
- explicitly configuring wlan0 in /etc/network/interfaces
- creating a /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf file

...but nothing seems to work.

I'm not sure what I did wrong, or what step I've skipped in trying to get wlan0 back as a non-bridged device -- I removed it from the bridge and then deleted the bridge itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work, because you cannot bridge a wireless interface with a virtual one. There is a way around that, I'll tell you how to do that in a second.

First, about your current problem: have you tried turning your machine off and back on again? Nothing of what you have done is permanent, so that, if you really feel desperate, rebooting will certainly work.

I am not sure what your problem exactly is. After erasing the bridge, you should erase the veth interfaces,

```
  ip link del dev veth0 type veth
```

deconfigure your wlan0 interface,

```
  ip link set wlan0 down
  ip addr flush dev wlan0
```

bring it up again,

```
  ip link set dev wlan0 up
```

and then let network-manager work its magic

```
  service network-manager start.
```

Like I said before, rebooting the pc will surely work. Also, and very important, you should not use **obsolete**, **deprecated** commands like *ifconfig, brctl**, and so on. The *iproute2* suite contains commands for all of this, including setting up virtual interfaces (something for which we once had to use openvpn) and creating bridges. If you do not know how to set up a bridge with *ip*, here we go:

```
  ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user root 

  ip link set tap0 up

  ip link add br0 type bridge

  ip link set tap0 master br0

  ip link set eth0 master br0

  ip addr add 10.173.10.1/24  dev br0

  ip link set br0 up
```

With this set of commands, we create a virtual interface called *tap0*, then a bridge called *br0*, then enslave *eth0* and *tap0* to the bridge, to which we assign an IP address of 10.173.10.1, then bring it all up. The three separate instances of bringing the interfaces up (for tap0, eth0, and br0) are required.

As for your problem. The trick to make this work is to use proxy.arp, which allows your pc (**not** your VM/Linux container/network namespace) to answer ARP queries in *their* stead.

In other words, by using IPv4 forwarding between your hardware interface and your virtual interface, you think you can connect your VM/LXC/NNS to your LAN as if it were a physical interface, but this is not true: you are forgetting the absolutely fundamental ARP traffic, which is what truly allows LAN to operate. So, the problem is: if I correctly forward IPv4 traffic, how can I also forward ARP traffic, so that my VM/LXC/NNS work? The trick is to use proxy-arp.

The full answer to that is in [Bohdi Zazen's blog](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/bridge-wireless-cards/), with the revealing title: *Bridge wireless cards*. He uses an obsolete package, *uml-utilities*, to create a virtual interface by means of the command *tunctl*: this is the only command for which he uses *uml-utilities*, so that you can safely neglect downloading the package, and use the command I wrote above to create a *tap* or *tun* interface, whichever you like, just modify the command accordingly. then create a veth pair for your LXC, and now create a bridge between tap0 and veth0. This bridge, called br0, is what you must *proxy-arp* for, instead of the simple tap0 interface described by Bohdi Zazen.

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic answer, and the informative link. Also, I had no idea ifconfig etc. were deprecated...time to re-learn linux networking.